# Prove that result that a linear transformation is continuous iff it transforms every sequence converge to zero into a bounded sequence.

Tags: linear-transformations

Proof.

(=>) Let $T$ be a continuous linear transformation.

Then we get $T$ is continuous at $0$.

Then $T$ is bounded.

Define $T$ transform sequence $x_{n}$ into $T(x_{n})$ ,then we will show $T(x_{n})$ is bounded sequence.

Since $x_{n}\rightarrow  0$ and $T$ is continuous, $T(x_{n})$ converges to $0$.

That is, $T(x_{n})$ is bounded sequence.

Is this proof correct? ####

And how to prove (<=) .

Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of $\implies$ is a bit excessive.  By the definition of continuity (in normed spaces), if $x_n \to 0$, then $T(x_n) \to T(0)$.  Since $\{T(x_n)\}$ is a convergent sequence, it is bounded.

For the other direction ($\Longleftarrow$): I prefer a proof by contrapositive.  Suppose that $T$ is *not* continuous.  Then, the image of the unit ball under $T$ is unbounded.  We can then take a sequence $y_n$ in the unit ball such that $\|T(y_n)\| \to \infty$.  Now, define
$$
x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\|T(y_n)\|}} y_n
$$
we then have $x_n \to 0$, but $\{T(x_n)\}$ is an unbounded sequence.

Comment: and how to prove in the other hand (<==) . Thanks

Comment: What do you think "for the other direction" means?

Comment: By the way: to make the arrows you want, the code is `\Longrightarrow` and `\Longleftarrow`. You could also use `\implies` for the right arrow.

Answer (score 0):

suppose $T$ isnot countinous then 
Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n \}_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\left\| T(x_n)\right\|> n\| x_n\| \ $, and so
$$
1<\frac{1}{n\|x_n\|}\|T(x_n)\|=\left\| T\left(\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}\right)\right\|\ \ .
$$
But $\left\|\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}\right\|\rightarrow 0\ $, and so by continuity at $0$
$$
\left\| T\left(\frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|}-0\right)\right\|\rightarrow\left\| T\left(0\right)\right\|=\|0\|=0,
$$
which is a contradiciton.

Comment: and how to prove in the other hand (<==) . Thanks

Comment: you mean that if $T$ is countinouse then if $x_n ‎\longrightarrow‎‎ 0$ how show that $T(x_n)‎\longrightarrow‎‎ 0$?

Comment: if T transform every sequence converging to zero into a bounded sequence then T is continuous linear transformation.

Comment: I havenot heard this before and I donot think it be correct.

Comment: ahh, thanks :-)

Comment: The statement *is* true, and is equivalent to saying that if $T$ is *not* continuous, then there exists a sequence converging to zero that $T$ maps to an unbounded sequence.

Comment: @Razieh you begin by supposing that $T$ is *not* continuous, and proceed to use the continuity of $T$ at zero. Something is wrong here.

Comment: I was trying to show that if   every sequence $x_{n}‎\longrightarrow 0$ give $T(x_{n})‎\longrightarrow 0$ Then $T$ is continuous.